# composer: timeout on installing a dependencies package

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install php phantomjs in my centos server using composer. 
It starts good but then it stops installing the package phantomjs.

[image]

Any ideas on why it stops there?

Comment: Have you tried running Composer again? This looks like a network issue.

Comment: yes, it's a week now that i am trying. anyway i resolved in another way! thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solved your problem. Please consider [answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). That way other users who have the same problem can learn how to solve it.